# Formidable javascript - get file from formData and resend

Tags: javascript, node.js, next.js, form-data, formidable

Here is my api handler.

```
// Retrieve data.
    const form = formidable({ multiples: true });

    form.parse(request, async (err: any, fields: any, files: any) => {
      if (!drupal) {
        return response.status(500).send('Empty drupal handler.');
      }

      const { fieldName, webformId } = fields;
      const file = files[fieldName];

      if (fieldName && webformId && file) {
        // Build api url.
        const url = drupal.buildUrl(
          `/webform_rest/${webformId}/upload/${fieldName}`
        );

        // Build file form data.
        const body = new FormData();
        body.append('file', file);

        // Send file data.
        if (file) {
          const result = await drupal.fetch(url.toString(), {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
              'Content-Type': 'application/octet-stream',
              'Content-Disposition':
                'file; filename="' + file.originalFilename + '"',
            },
            body,
            withAuth: true,
          });

          const resultData = await result.json();

          if (result.ok && 'fid' in resultData) {
            return response.status(200).json(resultData.fid[0]['value']);
          }
          return response.status(500).send({ error: result.statusText });
        }
      }
    });
```

I get here a `formData`. Subsequently, I want to send the file contained in this `formData` in post to another api.

everything looks fine except that on the other side of the second API I get a corrupted file, unable to open and small byte size.

what is wrong with my code?

thx

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that here `body.append('file', file);` the file variable is not of type File, it is a custom representation of the file that has meta information about it.